# Err 1305 ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST when querying MySQL on Heroku - does Heroku not support ST_Distance_Sphere?

Tags: mysql, heroku

I deployed a MySQL/Express/Node.js stack to Heroku (with ClearDB to connect to MySQL). All of my endpoints are working except for one search, which returns this error:

> code: 'ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST', errno: 1305, sqlState: '42000', sqlMessage: 'FUNCTION heroku_85b8b16ae133636.ST_Distance_Sphere does not exist'

I've found nothing about this error for this function in their support tickets or anywhere else. Does anyone know if it's possible to use ST_Distance_Sphere on Heroku? Do I need to install it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

ClearDB provisions MySQL 5.6 or 5.7 per their docs https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#the-cleardb-dedicated-mysql-complete-tutorial-local-setup.

ST_Distance_Sphere() is only supported in MySQL 5.7+

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).